# Proof that there exists an $x \in G$ such that $xa = b$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

So this is my challenge:

> Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$. Then $xa = b$ has a unique solution

I went about saying that $xa = b \iff xaa^{-1} = ba^{-1} \iff x = ba^{-1}$. 
$ba^{-1} \in G$ because $b, a^{-1} \in G$ and by the closure property the proposition follows.

To show uniqueness, I said that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ were both solutions then $x_1a = b = x_2a \iff x_1a = x_2a \iff x_1 = x_2$.

My book, however, provides this proof:

> Suppose that $xa = b$. We must show that $x$ exists. Multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ we have $x = ex = xaa^{-1} = ba^{-1}$

However, that proof is longer than mine, so I have a feeling that mine has flaws. Any comments?

Comment: if your text did what you have written then they are wrong because in the last part of the textbook's proof they have assumed $ax=b$, whereas you are given $xa=b$.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh, i was looking at the wrong part. Rewrote the question.

Comment: I personally see no flaw in your argument.  You showed existence and then uniqueness.  P.S. Your question is well-formulated.

Comment: your proof is correct.

Comment: @user46944 Thanks. I have been trying to make it that way, and I am glad my efforts paid off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xa=b\implies (xa)a^{-1}=ba^{-1}\implies x=ba^{-1}$
So solution is unique if it exists.

If $x=ba^{-1}$ we have $xa=(ba^{-1})a=b$. So the solution does exist and is unique.